# Get Intel XL710 network card working with Dell QSFP+

Tags: networking, centos

for budget reasons we decided to use Dell QSFP+ adapters instead of Intel adapters. We were hoping that we can set the option to allow unsupported SFP adapters.

Unfortunatly when we do `modprobe i40e allow_unsupported_sfp=1`

it restults into

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'i40e': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

Anyone else ran into this or a similar issue?

Comment: See `dmesg` as it advised you to do.

Comment: We didn't see anything odd with dmesg, but interresting that it is being detected via ethtool -m <network-id>. But it seems that the unsuppored_sfp opton works only for the lxgbe driver (10GBe). The i40e driver does not support this option.